# Help with a php if statement

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, if-statement

can somebody help me with this if statement?
My form appears every-time I load the page but it disappears after I submit the form!
Maybe it's the "endif" syntax that confuses me but I can't get this done properly...
here is the code:

```
<?php
if ($this->input->post('submit') && $this->input->post('categories')):
  foreach($tagedImages as $image):
  ?>
    <div class="thumb">
      <?php  echo'<a href="/toKoritsi/uploads/'.$image.'"/> <img src="/toKoritsi/uploads/thumbs/'.$image.'"/></a>' ?>
    </div>
  <?php
  endforeach;
elseif(isset($photosQuery) && count($photosQuery)):
  foreach($photosQuery->result_array() as $photo):
  ?>
    <div class="thumb">
      <?php echo'<a href="/toKoritsi/uploads/'.$photo['name'].'"/> <img src="/toKoritsi/uploads/thumbs/'.$photo['name'].'"/></a>' ?>
    </div>
  <?php
   endforeach;
endif;

$options = array(
  'bracelet'  => 'Bracelets',
  'ring'      => 'Rings',
  'bag'       => 'Bags',
  'earing'    => 'Earings'
);

echo form_open("toKoritsi/gallery");
echo form_dropdown('categories', $options, 'bracelet');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Choose');
echo form_close();
?>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use alternative syntax for foreach and if statements? Use braces please.

Comment: I tried to format it but gave up. That's impossible.

Comment: Agreed -- AAAGH!! My eyes!  You really need to deal with your indentation; its making your code very hard to read - as is the constant flipping between PHP and HTML. The use of the endif and endforeach syntax is making it worse, but I could live with that if the code was at least indented sensibly.

Comment: Maybe that's a *little* bit better... ;)

Comment: Ok guys I'll do it...but please suggest a proper way to format instead of cursing

Comment: Anybody can suggest a way for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Should `foreach($tagedImages as $image)` be `foreach($taggedImages as $image)`?

The formatting of your code is very ugly. If you are intent on getting nicely-formatted HTML output, perhaps you should consider using Tidy, or a template engine that offers that functionality.

Comment: thanks for the tip...but the problem is that the form is not displayed, all foreach loops are working fine

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to format your code properly.

I'd also recommend trying to consolidate your PHP into blocks, and keep it separate from your HTML.

You can do all the conditionals and echos WITHIN some of those HTML elements:

```
<div>
<?php /*...*/ ?>
</div>
```

as opposed to what you're doing now:

```
<?php /*...*/ ?>
<div>
<?php /*...*/ ?>
</div>
<?php /*...*/ ?>
```

In addition, things like these blocks make no sense:

```
    <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php endif;?>
```

Even if you had to break your code into small chunks, wouldn't it be easier to say:

```
<?php
    endforeach;
    endif;
?>
```

**EDIT**: This answer was provided before the question source was reformatted and cleaned up.  I was unable to even address the original issue until I could better see what was going on.

This might sound kind of dumb, but are you sure that your `gallery` controller is behaving correctly?  If you're submitting and there's an error in one of your CodeIgniter functions, it could be messing up the rendering after the submit.

Comment: although you are right, it really doesn´t answer the question at all.

Comment: That's fair, but I think when I answered this the code was such a mess that even trying to decipher the source was an issue.  Now at least we can see where the CodeIgniter allusions and braces are...

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what the url structure of your site looks like, but are you sure you are submitting the form to the right place?

According to the [CI user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html), it gets submitted to something like `/index.php/toKoritsi/gallery` but that depends on your config preferences.

Comment: yes the form is submitted to the right place because it does what it is supposed to do...but it doesn't get displayed after I submit it!

Comment: Do you have error messaging on? Perhaps the script is coming to a stop somewhere before the form gets displayed. I would check the server log and turn on all error messages.